# Change class in table column with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-index="0">
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </td>
            <td>....</td>
            <td>....</td>
            <td>
                <a class="fa fa-file-o"></a>
                <a class="fa fa-close"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr....
```

How can I change with jquery class "fa fa-check" to "fa fa-ban" in the first < td > and remove the content of the last < td > (fa-file-o and fa-close) in the row with data-index="0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('tr[data-index="0"]') // <-- this will get the td with data-index 0
  .find('td:first .fa-check').addClass('fa-ban').removeClass('fa-check') // <-- this will get the first td and replace fa-check to fa-ban
  .end() // <-- this will refer back to the tr with data index 0 initially referenced
  .find('td:last').empty(); // <-- this will search the last td and empty it
```

You need [.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) because after jquery gets the tr with index 0 and then iterates inside the first td we need to traverse back to the parent tr so that the last td can be captured.

```js
$('tr[data-index=0]')
  .find('td:first .fa-check').addClass('fa-ban').removeClass('fa-check')
  .end()
  .find('td:last').empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-index="0">
    <td>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>
      <a class="fa fa-file-o"></a>
      <a class="fa fa-close"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first:

```
$(".fa fa-check").addClass('fa-ban').removeClass('fa-check')
```

edit:

```
$('tr[data-index="0"]').find('td:first .fa fa-check').addClass('fa-ban').removeClass('fa-check')
```

Comment: thanks, how can I do it for a certain row (p.e. row 0)?